# Archive gmail messages from the notification center on an iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, gmail

I have an iPhone SE, model number MX9D2LL/A running software version 13.6.1.  On it, I have installed the Gmail app version 6.0.200712.  When I receive a banner notification for a new email, I can swipe down on the banner and see the options **Archive** and **Reply**.  However, when I later view that same notification in the Notification Center, I can not swipe down.  I can swipe right to open the message, swipe right gently to see the option **Open**, or swipe left to see the options **Manage**, **View**, and **Clear**.  Is there any way I can change my settings so that I can get the **Archive** and **Reply** options from the notification in the Notification Center?

Comment: I apologize if this is the wrong forum for this question.  I wasn't sure where to put it.

Answer (score 2):

1. Swipe left
2. Select **View**
3. The options **Archive** and **Reply** appear

It appears that I did not understand what **View** meant.  I thought it would open the message, but instead it views the notification.  In retrospect, it seems obvious that they wouldn't use the terms **View** and **Open** to mean and do the same thing in the same place.